# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ListView cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-studio

My ListView cannot be cast to TextView. I am new in android development and i am unable to solve this error. I am using android studio.

Code:

Adapter Code

```
public class AdapterFriends extends ArrayAdapter {
List list=new ArrayList();
public AdapterFriends(Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
}
public void add(FriendListElements object) {
    super.add(object);
    list.add(object);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view;
    view=convertView;
    ElementsHolder elemetsHolder;
    if (view==null){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.friends_list,parent,false);
        elemetsHolder=new ElementsHolder();
        elemetsHolder.tx_name=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.friend_name);
        elemetsHolder.tx_Gender=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.friend_gender);
        elemetsHolder.tx_address=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.friend_city);
        elemetsHolder.imageView=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.FriendsUserImage);
        view.setTag(elemetsHolder);
    }
    else
    {
        elemetsHolder=(ElementsHolder) view.getTag();

    }
    FriendListElements friendListElements=(FriendListElements)this.getItem(position);
    elemetsHolder.tx_name.setText(friendListElements.getName());
    elemetsHolder.tx_Gender.setText(friendListElements.getGender());
    elemetsHolder.tx_address.setText(friendListElements.getAddress());
    Picasso.with(getContext()).load(friendListElements.getImage()).error(R.drawable.emptyuser).into(elemetsHolder.imageView);

    return view;
}

static class ElementsHolder
{
    TextView tx_name,tx_Gender,tx_address;
    ImageView imageView;
}
}
```

Activity Code

```
public class Friends extends ActionBarActivity {
private Toolbar toolbar;
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
NavigationDrawer drawerFragment;
SessionManager session;
String JSONString,json_string;
ListView listView;

JSONObject jsonObject;
JSONArray jsonArray;
AdapterFriends adapterFriends;
ImageView imageView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_friends);
    toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    drawerLayout=(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    actionBarDrawerToggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawe_close);
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    drawerFragment=new NavigationDrawer();
    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
    drawerFragment.setUp((DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), toolbar);

     listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewFriends);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.userImageView);

    SearchFriends();
}




@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater= getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_actionbar, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
            .getActionView();
    if (null != searchView) {
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
                .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    }

    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            return true;
        }

        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {


            Intent i = new Intent(Friends.this, DisplaySearchResults.class);
            i.putExtra("name", query);
            startActivity(i);

            return true;
        }
    };
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}




@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id==R.id.info_id){
        session.logoutUser();
        return true;
    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}





public void SearchFriends(){
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
    String user_id = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_ID);
    new BackgroundSearch().execute(user_id);

}



class BackgroundSearch extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    String search_url;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        search_url = "http://www.server.com/Howdy/friendList.php";
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String user_id = params[0];

        try {
            URL url = new URL(search_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("user_id", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user_id, "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            // String response = "";
            // JSONString = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while ((JSONString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                // response += JSONString;
                stringBuilder.append(JSONString + "\n");
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return stringBuilder.toString().trim();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.parsejsontext);
        // textView.setText(result);
        json_string = result;
        ParseJson();


    }
}
public void ParseJson(){
    if(json_string==null)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Friends", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else {
        listView.setAdapter(adapterFriends);



        adapterFriends = new AdapterFriends(this, R.layout.friends_list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapterFriends);

        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(json_string);
            jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");

            int count = 0;
            String friend_id,name, Gender, address,image;
            while (count < jsonArray.length()) {
                JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
                friend_id=JO.getString("friend_id");
                name = JO.getString("name");
                Gender = JO.getString("Gender");
                address = JO.getString("address");

                image=("http://howdysendgreetings.com/Howdy/uploads/"+friend_id+".png");
                FriendListElements friendListElements = new FriendListElements(friend_id,name, Gender, address,image);
                adapterFriends.add(friendListElements);
               // Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(Uri.parse("http://howdysendgreetings.com/Howdy/uploads/"+user_id+".png")).
                   //     error(R.drawable.emptyuser).into(this.imageView);



                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {

                        FriendListElements friendListElements = (FriendListElements) adapterFriends.getItem(position);
                        Intent i = new Intent(Friends.this, FriendsProfile.class);
                        i.putExtra("friend_id", friendListElements.getFriend_id());
                        startActivity(i);


                    }
                });

                count++;


            }



        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



}
}
```

FriendsListElements Code:

```
public class FriendListElements {
private String friend_id,name,Gender,address,image;

public FriendListElements(String friend_id,String name,String Gender,String address,String image){
    this.setFriend_id(friend_id);
    this.setName(name);
    this.setGender(Gender);
    this.setAddress(address);
    this.image=image;
}
public String getFriend_id(){
    return friend_id;
}
public void setFriend_id(String friend_id) {
    this.friend_id = friend_id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getGender() {
    return Gender;
}

public void setGender(String gender) {
    Gender = gender;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address)
{
    this.address=address;
}
public  String getImage() {
    return image;
}
}
```

activity_friends.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.sendgreetings.Friends">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar">

    </include>
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listViewFriends">

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.example.NavigationDrawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawe_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
```

friends_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:id="@+id/FriendsUserImage"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/friend_name"
        android:onClick="SeeProfile"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Gender"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/friend_gender"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="City"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/friend_city"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

LOGCAT

```
04-21 17:49:20.879 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
 04-21 17:49:20.879 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 510: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
 04-21 17:49:20.879 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
 04-21 17:49:20.889 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
 04-21 17:49:20.889 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 532: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
 04-21 17:49:20.889 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
 04-21 17:50:03.979 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
 04-21 17:50:03.999 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
 04-21 17:50:04.019 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
 04-21 17:50:04.039 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
 04-21 17:50:09.159 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x01080a60 (t=7 e=2656) in package 0 (error -75)
 04-21 17:50:09.479 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings D/ProgressBar: updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
 04-21 17:50:09.479 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings D/ProgressBar: updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
 04-21 17:50:09.479 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings D/ProgressBar: updateDrawableBounds: right = 48
 04-21 17:50:09.479 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings D/ProgressBar: updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 48
04-21 17:50:10.489 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed. 
04-21 17:50:10.499 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
 04-21 17:50:10.499 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings W/ViewRootImpl: Dropping event due to root view being removed: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_MOVE, id[0]=0, x[0]=131.58879, y[0]=-22.309769, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=5, eventTime=350596751, downTime=350596671, deviceId=1, source=0x1002 }
04-21 17:50:10.529 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
04-21 17:50:14.729 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings I/Choreographer: Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-21 17:50:15.269 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings W/Settings: Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.
04-21 17:50:20.259 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-21 17:50:20.259 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41603c08)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings, PID: 2973
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ListView cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings.AdapterFriends.getView(AdapterFriends.java:50)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2742)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1274)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1186)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17375)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5380)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17375)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:868)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17375)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5380)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17375)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5380)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17375)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5380)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17375)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5380)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17375)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5380)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2563) 
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17375)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2308)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1408)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1610)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1263)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6611)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:812)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:612)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:582)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:798)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5641)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1288)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.bebo.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1104)
04-21 17:50:20.289 2973-2973/com.example.bebo.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you please post the error? Which line shows the error? You are trying to cast a ListView to a TextView. Are you sure the listViewFriends is a ListView and not  a text view?

Comment: What line exactly does this error occur on? Post the logcat , and remove the imports from the code, they're clogging the code unnecessarily.

Comment: i have posted the logcate @AswinPJ

Comment: Logcat is done @Vucko

Comment: cool, I see. Which line exactly is the line 50 in adapter? (`AdapterFriends.java:50`) is the place of the error

Comment: line 50:      elemetsHolder.tx_address=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.friend_city);        I know this line is showing the error but i don't know how to solve it please help me @Vucko

Comment: It would mean that `R.id.friend_city` is a ListView in the xml. That doesn't make any sense. Have you tried clean and rebuild?

Comment: R.id.friend_city is a textView in friend_list.xml and ListView is in activty.Xml file

Comment: @bebo Just `clean -> rebuild` your project.

Comment: In android studio how to do tha clean-> rebuild @jaydroider

Comment: @bebo Go to `Build` menu in that you can see `Clean Project` and `Rebuild Project`.

Comment: @bebo nothing wrong with code. I did notice a typo `elemetsHolder` > `elementsHolder`.

Comment: thank you very much .. GOD bless u.. its working now @jaydroider

Comment: Glad to help you :). @bebo

Comment: lol nice spot. I knew I saw no error also :D